# Using child's property in parent's methods

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have many model classes that I populate with data fetched from web api service. All the classes share many properties like creation date etc.:

```
public class Car
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Utworzył")]
        public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Data utworzenia")]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int? LmBy { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Zmodyfikował")]
        public string LmByName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Data modyfikacji")]
        public DateTime? LmOn { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int TenantId { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public string TenantName { get; set; }
    }
```

All the model classes also have methods to create/update related entity in db. For example "Car" class's methods are:

```
public async Task<bool> Add()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"CreateCar?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&UserId=" + RuntimeSettings.UserId;
                var serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
                var content = new StringContent(serializedProduct, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var rString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    T _this = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rString);
                    this.CarId = _this.CarId;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        public async void Edit()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"EditCar?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&id={0}&UserId={1}";
                var serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
                var content = new StringContent(serializedProduct, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PutAsync(String.Format(url, this.CarId, RuntimeSettings.UserId), content);
            }
        }
```

So I thought it'd be good to make 1 model class for all other to derive from. It'd have all the shared properties:

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
    {
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Utworzył")]
        public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Data utworzenia")]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int? LmBy { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Zmodyfikował")]
        public string LmByName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Data modyfikacji")]
        public DateTime? LmOn { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int TenantId { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public string TenantName { get; set; }
    }
```

It would be used like below:

```
public class Car : Entity<Car>
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem I have is with the methods. If I keep them in parent class (not to create them for each child since 90% of logic is shared), I can't use child's id property (CarId) in the parent's methods simply because such properties don't exist in parent:

```
public async Task<bool> Add()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"Create{typeof(T).Name}?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&UserId=" + RuntimeSettings.UserId;
                var serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
                var content = new StringContent(serializedProduct, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var rString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    T _this = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rString);
                    this.CarId = _this.CarId; // CarId doesn't exist in parent, it's child's property
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        public async void Edit()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"Edit{typeof(T).Name}?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&id={0}&UserId={1}";
                var serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
                var content = new StringContent(serializedProduct, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PutAsync(String.Format(url, this.CarId, RuntimeSettings.UserId), content); // CarId doesn't exist in parent, it's child's property
            }
        }
```

Probably If I used more generic ID property names (Id instead of CarId) it would be simpler, but assuming I must stick with the custom names ("CarId","EmployeeId") - what are my choices?

Maybe I could create generic ID property in parent and somehow bind it with child's appropriate id field when I'm inheriting?

Comment: You need multiple Add() methods.  One in the base class that does common code and then one in each inherited class the does unique code.  The inherited methods will call the base method to do common code.

Comment: "So I thought it'd be good to make 1 model class for all other to derive from. It'd have all the shared properties:" Good idea, however you won´t generics for that. A simple `abstract` super-class is absoluetely sufficient, that contains the **common** behaviour. The behaviour which is **specific** to a certain class however should surely be implemented there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of an `abstract` super-class was absoluetely good. However it doesn´t need to be generic. It should just contain all the **common** behaviour. Having said this your `Entitity`-class should also have an `abstract ID`-property:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Utworzył")]
    public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data utworzenia")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int? LmBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Zmodyfikował")]
    public string LmByName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data modyfikacji")]
    public DateTime? LmOn { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string TenantName { get; set; }
    public abstract int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your implementing class you can implement the `abstract` property to return the concrete `CarId` for example:

```
public class Car : Entity
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public int Id => CarId;
}
```

Alternativly you may completely omit the `CarId`-property from your `Car`-class and only have the `Id` from the abstract class:

```
public class Car : Entity
{
    public int Id get; set; }
}
```

No matter which of those two approaches you chose your base-class now **has** an `Id`-member making your `Add`-method look like the following:

```
public async Task<bool> Add()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"Create{this.GetType().Name}?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&UserId=" + RuntimeSettings.UserId;
        var serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        var content = new StringContent(serializedProduct, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var rString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // you don´t need to knoe the actual type, all you need is its Id, so an Entity is just fine
            Entity e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rString);
            this.Id = e.Id; 
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it put me in the right direction. Unfortunately, there are errors. First, Id is a field in Car class whereas in Entity it's property. I changed it in Car to property too, in a form `public override int Id { set => value = CarId; get => CarId; }`. Second, I had to remove 'abstract' from Entity class, as with it I couldn't create instance of it with `Entity e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rString);`. Having done all this, my code compiles and all works fine without "Add". For some reason e.Id=0 after adding, probably there's error in the Id property I created for Car class

Comment: tested it a little more and I think I understand. What gets back from Json deserialization is of type Entity (also tried Entity<Car> with same result) which by design does not have CarId property. As the object fetched from web api doesn't have "Id" property (but DOES have "CarId"), deserializer can't deserialize it properly... I'm afraid this can't be fixed

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Utworzył")]
    public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data utworzenia")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int? LmBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Zmodyfikował")]
    public string LmByName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data modyfikacji")]
    public DateTime? LmOn { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string TenantName { get; set; }
}


public class Car : Entity
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you must override the methods for every different class to handle.

Comment: Thanks Marco, but honestly speaking I was looking for more generic solution (so I don't have to override the methods). With overriding it'd be simple but I want to keep as much code as possible in parent. Of course I don't know if it can be done so there's a chance your solution is the best

Comment: There isn't a way, if you don't want to write more than 1 method, you can check "this" 's type and cast the object and add an if for every object but if you must do this, at this point it's better to override.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the repository pattern. In repository pattern, create a base repository with the basic CRUD operations on properties in your Entity abstract class. And then, create derived repository classes for operations on entity specific properties. 
If you want still want to do in your model classes, you can do as below.

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
    {
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Utworzył")]
        public string CreatedByName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Data utworzenia")]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int? LmBy { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Zmodyfikował")]
        public string LmByName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Data modyfikacji")]
        public DateTime? LmOn { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public int TenantId { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)]
        public string TenantName { get; set; }
        public virtual void Add(){
//operation using base properties
         }

public class Car : Entity<Car>
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public override void Add(){
            //do custom operation or call base.Add() or whatever you want
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by implementing small work-around. "Edit" worked already when I put HimBromBeere's suggestion in place. For "Add" to work, I had to changed my Entity class to:

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
    {
        [Browsable(false)]
        public string AddedItem { get; set; }

        public virtual async Task<bool> Add()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"Create{typeof(T).Name}?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&UserId=" + RuntimeSettings.UserId;
                var serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
                var content = new StringContent(serializedProduct, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var rString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    AddedItem = rString;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Serwer zwrócił błąd przy próbie utworzenia rekordu. Wiadomość: " + result.ReasonPhrase);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And deriving class was changed to:

```
public class Car : Entity<Car>
    {
        public async override Task<bool> Add()
        {
            bool x = await base.Add();
            if (x)
            {
                try
                {
                    Car _this = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(AddedItem);
                    this.CarId = _this.CarId;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Tworzenie nowego rekordu zakończone powodzeniem!");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I found HimBromBeere's answer most helpful and so chose his post as answering my question.